# Is this Matrix notation same as the summation terms?

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices, H(K,L) of size 5*3 and W(K,R) of size 5*4.

I have to find out a term in MATLAB. 
∑H(k,l)W(k,r) where the sum is over k and l.

How can I check whether the term above is same as the matrix notation (H^T)W ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is tagged Matlab, I'll use Matlab notation.

You can think through problems like this by writing out both
expressions.

The (l,r)th entry of `H.'*W` is `sum(H(:,l).*W(:,r))`; you can
think of this as summing over k.  You also want to sum over l, so you
need to find the sum of the columns:

```
result= sum(H.'*W);
```

You can test this:

```
result2 = zeros(1,size(W,2));
for l = 1:size(H,2)
  for k = 1:size(W,1)
    for r = 1:size(W,2)
      result2(r) = result2(r) + H(k,l)*W(k,r);
    end
  end
end

max(abs(result-result2))
```